# Calculated member, or scope MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a calculated member, which brings up the current members personal balance as a figure, and besides that I would like the show the network balance of the current member. So let's say I am a franchise and I have my personal shop, and also several other affiliated shops which I take care of.

1. My personal balance would be -> Eur1000
2. My network balance would be -> my Eur1000 balance + (All my affiliated shops balances)

I have done the personal balance part, however I am trying to create a calculated member within an MDX query to show the network balance, and am getting #Error - so I am doing something wrong. My code is as follows;

```
with member  [Measures].[Network Balance] as 

      SUM(NULL:DESCENDANTS([Dim User Balance].[UserIdHierarchy].CurrentMember,0,self),
        [measures].[balance])

member [Measures].[Peronal Balance] as 

      SUM(NULL:[Dim User Balance].[UserIdHierarchy].CurrentMember,
        [measures].[balance])
```

Seems to be that the member with member  [Measures].[Network Balance] is not liking the descendants function. Any ideas how I can go around this? Does scope work better in this context?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the error message that you get? If you run the query in Management Studio, you can double click the cell showing "#Error" to see details on the error. How do can we determine which shops are affiliated to you?

Comment: Hi @FrankPl the [Dim User Balance].[UserIdHierarchy] is an internal hierarchy in the dimension. If I filter with a a particular shop X, I will see shop X and his/her descendants. So all the descendants of X are affiliated to shop X. Does it make sense? I would like to display the total balance of shop X, and his/her descendants thus I am trying to use the calculated SUM of the SELF_AND_AFTER - however to no avail. Any ideas? Ignore the #Error I got around that but with incorrect figures. I am still trying to figure out a way to calculate the total balance.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what you want to achieve with the `NULL :` construct.

As far as I understand your description, the `Personal Balance` is just `[Measures].[balance]` without any need to adapt that.

And the `[Measures].[Network Balance]` would just be

```
Sum(Descendants([Dim User Balance].[UserIdHierarchy].CurrentMember, 0, SELF_AND_AFTER),
    [Measures].[balance])
```